# C# Declaration Question

Tags: c#

I am very new to c#, but I am learning more every day.

I am wondering what the following means:

```
private DataIdentifier dataIdentifier;
```

Why do they write like this? It is almost the same name but they use big D in the first word.

Comment: I liked it better with the misspellings, made me think of a fuzzy kitten learning c#

Answer (score 7):

This declares a member variable (i.e. a "field") in a class.

`private` is the [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It specifies that the variable can only be accessed from within the class. The access modifier is optional, and defaults to `private` (but it's considered best practice to be explicit anyway).

`DataIdentifier` is the [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) of the variable (i.e., only instances of the `DataIdentifier` class can be put into the variable).

`dataIdentifier` is the name of the variable. This is what you write in the code when you want to access the object that's being held in the variable.

Note: Technically, objects are not actually "in" a variable; the variable is typically a pointer to a location in memory where the object actually is (it "references" an object).

As you learn more C#, you'll see a common idiom where the name of the property is the same as the name of the type:

```
public SpaceShip SpaceShip;
```

This is allowed since the compiler is smart enough to know whether you're referring to the variable or the class itself when you type `SpaceShip` in your code, just from the context.

Comment: Good answer. However, the `public SpaceShip SpaceShip;` will only compile if `SpaceShip` *is not defined in* the current type. (Variables/methods/properties can't share names with enclosed types -- that would just be *too* confusing!)

Comment: @pst: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware! Nested types aren't all that common in practice, though.

Answer (score 1):

`DataIndentifier` is a type.

`dataIdentifier` is the name of a field of that type.

The similarity of the names is entirely coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

```
private DataIdentifier dataIdentifier;
```

`DataIdentifier` is a Type whereas `dataIdentifier` is a variable declared of that type

Like

```
private int a;
```

where `int` is a type and `a` is a variable of type Int

Comment: It is *convention* in C# that types are in UpperCase. While `private DataIdentifier DataIdentifier;` is valid in many cases (first `DataIdentifier` is type, 2nd is variable name just as above), that just becomes confusing...

Comment: @pst, yes it's. Also, That's a `Camel case` type naming and there is another type I don't recall now. I prefer not to declare the variable with the same name as the type name ... so that remving the confusion.

Comment: DataIdentifier is UpperCase (or CapWords or...) while dataIdentifier is camelCase (the difference is if the first character is also capitalized).

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered several times over, but I would like to instead recommend what I believe to be the **BEST** introductory book for C#. Even if you don't like learning from books, you'll like this one:

[Head First C#](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/)

Check out the free chapters and if you like it, buy it. I guarantee you won't be sorry. Hope it helps.

*DISCLAMER: I am in no way affiliated to OReilly Media or any of its subsidiaries... ;)*

Comment: True ... I like `Head First` series too

Answer (score 0):

It is just another type of notation. It's really a silly variable name. I wouldn't recommend you follow the same convention. `DataIdentifier` is the class/object type. `private` is the access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataIdentifier` is the type (class or struct) and `dataIdentifer` is the name.

Answer (score 0):

DataIdentifier is the type of the variable
dataIdentifier is the name of the variable (it is of the type DataIdentifier)

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive.  DataIdentifier and dataIdentifier are two different things.

Here DataIdentifier is the type and dataIdentifier is the variable.

Comment: In this case, even if they *were* the same case, they would *still* refer to two different things just based on *where* they are used in the grammar productions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful for you to relate the example to the actual [grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645750%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) of C#.

```
field-declaration:
    attributesopt   field-modifiersopt   type   variable-declarators   ;

field-modifiers:
    field-modifier
    field-modifiers   field-modifier

field-modifier:
    new
    public
    protected
    internal
    private
    static
    readonly
    volatile

variable-declarators:
    variable-declarator
    variable-declarators   ,   variable-declarator

variable-declarator:
    identifier
    identifier   =   variable-initializer

variable-initializer:
    expression
    array-initializer
```